# How to convert this mySql query to PDO format...?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How should i write my PDO Prepare and bindValue/param statement for this type of query where i **check whether the value is not null then only add it to the query string**.....

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM cabs WHERE DATE='$date' ";
if ($mode!=='' || $mode!=="")
  $query .="AND MODE='$mode' ";

if ($tfno!=='')
  $query .="AND TFNO='$tfno' ";
  $query .="ORDER BY TIME";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer, without testing:

```
<?php
$params = array(':date' => $date);
$query = "SELECT * FROM cabs WHERE DATE=':date' ";
if ($mode!=='' || $mode!=="") {
  $query .="AND MODE=':mode' ";
  $params[':mode'] = $mode;
}

if ($tfno!=='') {
  $query .="AND TFNO=':tfno' ";
  $params[':tfno'] = $tfno;
}
$query .="ORDER BY TIME";

$req = $dbh->prepare($query);
$req->execute($params);
```

Just push in the param array each time your query gets more filters, and using a name should be easier, I'm not sure that `array_push` would preserve the order, so ..

Comment: If `array_push` didn't preserve order, then it's be a pretty stupid function. That said, I agree with using named parameters - makes your query much easier to maintain.

Comment: ohkk will try it asap

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I remember having issues with default index in array, can't remember what. So yeah, seems obvious that array_push would do the job, but since I got owned with array once ...